# Add a ButtonField in a ListField row in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am new in Blackberry. Can someone please give me a simple example on how to add clickable ButtonField in a row of a ListField so that the list shows something like this?
[image]

I stuck on this. Please help me.

Comment: you can't add button field to list field

Comment: you need to create custom field

Comment: I agree with koti - this is impossible with ListField. If your list is relatively short (no more than 10-20 items), then you can go with a bunch of custom Managers (one per item) which can hold ButtonField.

Comment: Ok thanks for your support. It may help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

ListField does not support ButtonField instances on list rows. Screenshot you have provided does not show ListField instance. It is a combination of non-list fields and layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ButtonField` on a list row (only one button per list row) and on the `navigationClick`:

```
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    int selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex();
    TableRowManager selectedRow=(TableRowManager) rows.elementAt(selectedIndex);
    Field field = ((TableRowManager) rows.elementAt(selectedIndex)).getField(0);
    if(field instanceof ButtonField){
        field.getChangeListener().fieldChanged(field, 0);
                    return true;
    }
            return false;
 }
```